# How can I convert a TIMESTAMP_NTZ what I know is in UTC to TIMESTAMP_TZ in Snowflake SQL?

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a column of type `TIMESTAMP_NTZ` and it contains timestamp that I know are on UTC timezone. Mainly I want to convert to `TIMESTAMP_TZ` because I have other columns that are `TIMESTAMP_TZ` and I want to be able to do operations involving both.

I've tried to generate a `TIMESTAMP_TZ` in the following ways:

```
SELECT 
   '2019-10-24 12:07:24.000'::timestamp_ntz as orig -- a literal timestamp_ntz 
   ,convert_timezone('UTC', 'UTC', orig) -- the 3-args version of convert_timezone will always return a TIMESTAMP_NTZ
   ,convert_timezone('UTC', orig) -- the 2-args assumes that orig timezones is session's current timezone 
;
```

Just to be clear I want to convert `2019-10-24 12:07:24.000` to `2019-10-24 12:07:24.000 +0000`

Is there any function or operator in Snowflake that allows me to say treat this `TIMESTAMP_NTZ` as  `TIMESTAMP_TZ` in timezone X?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to just suffix a "Z" onto the end of the original TIMESTAMP_NTZ and then convert it to a TIMESTAMP_TZ like the following:

```sql
-- Set timezone to something which isn't UTC 
alter session set TIMEZONE = 'America/Los_Angeles';
-- Make sure the timestamp TZ output format is as you'd expect
alter session set TIMESTAMP_TZ_OUTPUT_FORMAT = "YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF3 TZHTZM";

select 
       '2019-10-24 12:07:24.567'::timestamp_ntz as orig, -- Outputs "2019-10-24 12:07:24.567000000"
       (orig::varchar||'Z')::timestamp_tz timestamp_with_tz --Outputs "2019-10-24 12:07:24.567 +0000"
;
```

Answer (score 5):

There are two ugly hacks that you can use

- [TIMESTAMP_TZ_FROM_PARTS](https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/sql-reference/functions/timestamp_from_parts.html): Construct a new `TIMESTAMP_TZ` using all the components from the source `TIMESTAMP_NTZ` and provide the timezone as the last parameter. It's very verbose. See the example below.
- [TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ](https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/sql-reference/functions/to_timestamp.html) and [CONCAT](https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/sql-reference/functions/concat.html) : Serialize the `TIMESTAMP_NTZ` as a string / `VARCHAR` add the timezone string at the end of it and reparse the whole thing as a `TIMESTAMP_TZ`.

```
select 
       '2019-10-24 12:07:24.567'::timestamp_ntz as orig
       ,TIMESTAMP_TZ_FROM_PARTS( year(orig), month(orig),day(orig), hour(orig), minute(orig), second(orig) , date_part(nanosecond, orig), 'UTC' ) 
       ,TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ(orig::varchar || ' +0000')
;

--
2019-10-24 12:07:24.567        -- TIMESTAMP_NTZ (UTC)
2019-10-24 12:07:24.567 +0000  -- TIMESTAMP_TZ  (UTC)
2019-10-24 12:07:24.567 +0000  -- TIMESTAMP_TZ  (UTC)
```

Comment: Thank you! I've been trying to find a solution that doesn't involve altering the session forever. This sure is ugly, but it works :)

Answer (score 4):

This works if you know the local timezone of your account, user, or session.  For me, it's 'America/New_York':

```
SELECT current_timestamp::timestamp_ntz as orig, 
       convert_timezone('UTC',convert_timezone('UTC','America/New_York',orig)::timestamp_tz);
```

Also, if this is a 1-time conversion, you could run:

```
ALTER SESSION SET TIMEZONE = 'UTC'
```

This would temporarily display values as UTC and you could convert them to _tz with:

```
SELECT convert_timezone('UTC', orig)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest setting the session timezone to UTC first.

`ALTER SESSION SET TIMEZONE = 'UTC';`

If you can't do that, and you don't know what the session timezone is, you could calculate that as part of your query:

```
SELECT
    DATEDIFF(minute, CONVERT_TIMEZONE('UTC', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)::timestamp_ntz, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) AS utc_offset,
    '2019-10-24 12:07:24.567'::timestamp_ntz AS orig,
    CONVERT_TIMEZONE('UTC', DATEADD(minute, utc_offset, orig)) as tz_time;
```

This avoids any string manipulation (which I strongly recommend to avoid).

Answer (score -1):

How about converting to local time zone and using convert_timezone to get the timezone

`SELECT '2019-10-24 12:07:24.000'::timestamp_ntz::timestamp_ltz as orig ,convert_timezone('UTC', orig); 0/p= 2019-10-24 19:07:24.000 +0000`

Comment: No, that assumes that orig is already in the local timezone which is not. And the conversion would be is totally wrong. You can look at your own output `2019-10-24 19:07:24.000 +0000` that is **not** the expected result: `2019-10-24 12:07:24 +0000`